# JS appendChild is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, tags, appendchild

so I know this question has been asked so many times but I still haven't found a solution to my problem:

HTML

```
<div class="thumbnails"></div>
```

JS

```
function createImg(index){
    tempImg.src = paths[index];
}

function appendImg(){
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = tempImg.src;

    createImg(index++);
    img.setAttribute('id', 'firsts');
    ** document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnails').appendChild(img); **
}
```

I want to append the newly created image/s to my div. I've tried many versions of doing it but nothing seemed to work.

If I use "document.body.appendChild(img);" this works just fine but it isn't what I need.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName('thumbnails')` returns a collection. Index it. `getElementsByClassName('thumbnails')[0].appendChild(img)` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: Besides reading the duplicated question, read documentation also helps a developer: [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for this:

```
document.querySelector(".thumbnails").appendChild(img);
```

as `querySelector()` returns the first element within the document that matches the specified selector. But `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names and this array-like object does not have any `appendChild` method.

Comment: That worked. Learned my lesson. Thank you!!